# Using super with __getitem__ versus subscript

Tags: python, super

I'm writing a `dict` which only has tuples of positive integers as keys.  If the key is unknown and one of the elements of the tuple is `1`, lookup should return a default value of `0`.  Any other unknown key should raise `KeyError`.

This works fine:

```
class zeroDict(dict):
    '''
    If key not in dict and an element of the tuple is 
    a 1, impute the value 0.
    '''    
    def __init__self():
        super().__init__()
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        try:
            return super().__getitem__(key)
        except KeyError:
            if 1 in key:
                return 0
            else:
                raise
```

This does not:

```
class zDict(dict):
    '''
    If key not in dict and an element of the tuple is 
    a 1, impute the value 0.
    '''    
    def __init__self():
        super().__init__()
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        try:
            return super()[key]
        except KeyError:
            if 1 in key:
                return 0
            else:
                raise
```

When I try to read a value from `zDict` I get `TypeError: 'super' object is not subscriptable`.

The only difference between the implementations is that `zeroDict` says

```
return super().__getitem__(key)
```

and `zDict` says

```
return super()[key]
```

However, `help(dict.__getitem__)` prints

```
__getitem__(...)
    x.__getitem__(y) <==> x[y]
```

which seems to say that the two statements are equivalent.  What is going on here?

Comment: `super()` doesn't return an instance of the class; it returns a proxy to the *class*. If `d` is a `dict`, `d[3]` is equivalent to `d.__getitem__(3)`, not `dict[3]`.

Comment: "Note that super() is implemented as part of the binding process for explicit dotted attribute lookups such as super().__getitem__(name). ... Accordingly, super() is undefined for implicit lookups using statements or operators such as super()[name]." https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#super

Comment: @chepner But I'm using `super()` in both cases.  Why does it work in one and not the other?

Comment: @georg Thank you.  Please write that as an answer, so I can accept it.

Comment: Because, like I said, `super()` doesn't return an instance of `zeroDict`; `super()[key]` and `super().__getitem__(key)` simply *aren't* the same thing. `super().__getitem__` is not the same as `self.__getitem__`.

Comment: @chepner So what you're saying is that the help on `dict.__getitem__` is irrelevant, is that it?

Comment: In this case, yes, because `super()` doesn't return the class `dict`.

Comment: @chepner I get it now, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As others have explained, the reason that `super()` is not working here is because it returns a *super object*, which is a proxy object that handles dispatching dotted attribute access to the next class in the method resolution order.

That being said, you shouldn't be overriding `__getitem__` here, the python data-model provides something *just for this case*, it's the [`__missing__` method](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__missing__):

> `object.__missing__(self, key)`
>
> implement `self[key]` for dict subclasses when key is not in the
>   dictionary.Called by `dict.__getitem__()`

So, do something like this:

```
class ZeroDict(dict):
    def __missing__(self, key):
        if 0 in key:
            return 0
        else:
            raise KeyError(key)
```

And a demonstration:

```
>>> class ZeroDict(dict):
...     def __missing__(self, key):
...         if 0 in key:
...             return 0
...         else:
...             raise KeyError(key)
...
>>> d = ZeroDict()
>>> d[(1, 0)] = 'foo'
>>> d
{(1, 0): 'foo'}
>>> d[1, 0]
'foo'
>>> d[1, 1]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 6, in __missing__
KeyError: (1, 1)
>>> d[0, 1]
0
>>>
```

Comment: Thank you, I wasn't aware of __missing__